# sed windows replace string containing space

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a string `AUD A0-FX.20` with `AUD/USD.20` using sed for windows through the windows cmd shell.

I dont think windows shell handles spaces in strings well. Here is what I'm running -

```
SED -e s{AUD A0-FX.20{AUD/USD.20{  "C:\sed\bin\text.txt" > "C:\sed\bin\text1.txt"
```

but I get an error `SED: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated`s' command`

I'm using `{` as the delimiter because i already have a `/` in the replacement string. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using `sed` for windows from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: don't you need to quote your `s{..{..{`  under windows?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your question because can't test in Windows, but I will give two suggestions:

1. `.` is special for `sed` and matches any character. Escape it like `\.`
2. Quote your `sed` instructions, with single or double quotes, like `"s{...{...{"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed "s|AUD A0-FX\.20|AUD/USD.20|"
```

Comment: If I recall, single quotes have no special meaning in a CMD shell, duoble quotes are required.